# mcs: The type or namespace name `XXX' could not be found ... missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, .net, build, mono

I am attempting to build a single cs file from the command line using mcs. I am using an external library in the c# code:

`using SomeLib`

However, I can't find out how to specify the required library to mcs. How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Are you really using `xbuild` with only a `.cs` file, no project file? That doesn't work at all on my system. I suspect either you are using `mcs` instead of `xbuild`, or you've created a project file containing a single `.cs` file. If it's either of those, the answer depends on which one it is.

Comment: @hvd: Ah, you're right I meant to write mcs instead. I have updated the title to reflect the correction.

Comment: What library are you trying to include? Or does this happen with many different libraries?

Comment: @RicardoAltamirano: its a thitd paty library (clrzmq: from the zeromq project). Regarding the second question, the problem is that I simply don't know how to pass a reference (a shared lib [clrzmq.dll]) to mcs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `gmcs` and pass the library using the **r** specifier as follows:

```
gmcs filename.cs -r:libthirdparty
```